# CCK in input form, but not in node structure

Tags: php, drupal, view, drupal-views

I have a content type (Witl) that the user creates. On the creation form, the user selects an option out of a list of nodes that's generated from a view (VOut). Right now I store that option as a node reference on Witl.

I need to restructure things around, so that this node reference isn't stored on Witl itself, instead eventually stored as a node reference on another node. However the user can only create Witl content types. This means that I have to figure out a way to present that view (the selection list) to the user on Witl, yet not save it on Withl at all. Can it be done? Is there a way to use one content type creation form only as a way to present the view, yet not store the data on this content type?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this can be done.

Instead of creating the field on the content type Witl, implement `hook_form_alter()` to add the field dynamically to the content creation form. Then, implement `hook_nodeapi()` to save this value somewhere, after the form is submitted.

I'm not sure if it's the best way, though.

Answer (score 3):

Is it really important that the reference is not stored in the Witl node? There are several modules that try to address the problem of creating and displaying bi-directional relationships between nodes, but as far as I know, none of them save the reference *only* in the referenced node.

Suppose you have two nodes, node A (type: Witl) and node B (type: other), and you need to do something with the reference from B to A. This is your situation, right?

The [Corresponding Node References](http://drupal.org/project/cnr) module takes the 'easy' approach and will take the reference in A to B and duplicate it as a reference in B to A.

Other modules, like [Node Relationships](http://drupal.org/project/noderelationships) and [Reverse Node Reference](http://drupal.org/project/reverse_node_reference) argue that databases should not contain duplicate data and try to resolve the relationship in A to B when looking at node B.

If it is indeed a must that the reference, when added in A, is *only* stored in B, then personally, I would take the code from Corresponding Node References as a basis for a custom module.

Answer (score 2):

I believe its possible to do this using the following module

http://drupal.org/project/nodereference_url

Here is a tutorial of the module:

http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode37

This tutorial might confuse you a bit so I would recommend you read the documentation for the module first.

Basically, what this module will do is allow you to link a VOut to a Witl. Right now as you explained, a Witl links to a VOut. But after using the nodereference URL module you will be able to have a node reference field within VOut that links back to a Witl.